# How can I specify ALL guids for getNoteWithResultSpec()?

Tags: ruby, evernote, evernote-app-notebook

New to evernote api using Ruby. Using the example to try to get a list of notes from notebooks. That example seems pretty messed up though so I don't think I'm properly configured. I'm stuck on what to put to include content from this page, http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNoteWithResultSpec

def note_store
   @note_store ||= client.note_store
 end

note_store.getNoteWtihResultSpec(auth_token, true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NoteStore.getNoteWithResultSpec` is meant to retrieve one specific note. If you need to find all notes belonging to a certain notebook, use [NoteStore.findNotesMetadata](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_findNotesMetadata) to find notes. In passed [NoteFilter](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Struct_NoteFilter) structure you need to provide the guid of your notebook.

Note that this means you will need to do as many `NoteStore.getNoteWithResultSpec` calls as the number of notes you have. A more elegant solution would be to synchronize your notebook: use [NoteStore.getFilteredSyncChunk](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getFilteredSyncChunk) repeatedly to get note data in chunks. In [SyncChunkFilter](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Struct_SyncChunkFilter) structure specify the list of notebook guids you're interested in (which can be just one).

Also, if your goal is to keep up with the changes in that notebook, instead of periodically polling for new data with `NoteStore.getFilteredSyncChunk`, you can request a setup of a [webhook](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/polling_notification.php#webhooks) to get notified of changes.