# How to Access A Note's Content

Tags: evernote

I would like to save all the Notes in my Notebooks as plain text files. I am attempting to access the note's content with `note_content = note_store.getNoteContent(developer_token,first_notebook.guid)`

But I get the following error:
`evernote.edam.error.ttypes.EDAMNotFoundException: EDAMNotFoundException(identifier='Note.guid', key='e49967e8-3247-4560-8ce5-40577cc2166f')`

But I know the guid is valid because `first_notebook.guid` gives `e49967e8-3247-4560-8ce5-40577cc2166f`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`getNoteContent` retrieves individual notes, so it expects a GUID of a *note*, not a *notebook*.

See [How can I specify ALL guids for getNoteWithResultSpec()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775651/how-can-i-specify-all-guids-for-getnotewithresultspec) for additional information on how to find or sync notes.