# How to access recognized text in EverNote using their SDK(python)

Tags: ocr, evernote

The evernote software gives option to export notebook into .enex file. This can be parsed to get the recognized text and its location in the image.
(As shown in http://blog.evernote.com/tech/2013/07/18/how-evernotes-image-recognition-works/)
Now I want to get this recognized text through Evernote's python SDK. Here's what I have done till now:

1. Created a notebook in https://sandbox.evernote.com I am able to
   search for text in the note from the browser.
2. Created a dev token for accessing this notebook.
3. I am able to iterate over my notebooks and get their guid. And using
   that able to access note inside the notebooks.

   ```
       notebooks = self.noteStore.listNotebooks()

       print "Notebooks:"
       for notebook in notebooks:
           print notebook.name, notebook.guid
           # display notes in the notebook
           print self.noteStore.findNoteCounts(self.dev_token, NoteFilter(notebookGuid=notebook.guid), True)
           spec = NotesMetadataResultSpec(includeTitle=True)
           # The following provides the note guid
           print self.noteStore.findNotesMetadata(self.dev_token, NoteFilter(notebookGuid=notebook.guid), 0, 10, spec)`
   ```

   4. But I am not able to access the recognized text in the note.
      Tried:

   `note = self.noteStore.getNote(self.dev_token, note_guid, False, True, True, True)
    for r in note.resources:
           print "resource guid: ", r.guid
           resource = self.noteStore.getResource(r.guid, True, False, True, False)
           print resource.data.body`

Also tried(as mentioned in [How to Access A Note's Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397637/how-to-access-a-notes-content)):

```
noteContent = self.noteStore.getNoteContent(self.dev_token, note_guid)
    print noteContent
```

This gives something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd">
<en-note><div><br clear="none"/></div><br/><en-media hash="dhhd2e240c83140sjskca0bf6e8c9661fd1c3472" type="image/jpeg"/></en-note>
```

But in http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/image_recognition.php
recoExample.py is able to extract the recognized text. Only difference between that and mine is I am running on sandbox environment.

What should I do to get the recognized text?

Comment: Where do you want to use this recognition data? Note that Evernote already uses this recognition data for searching, and all external uses of recognition data are prohibited by [Evernote API License Agreement](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/api_license.php), see item 1.8.10 of that document.

Comment: @IgorAfanasyev
So the recoExample.py mentioned in
http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/image_recognition.php is not for public usage?

Comment: This example is provided to explain how the recognition data is stored. This data can be used legally to e.g. implement local search or search highlighting in images within third-party Evernote clients. But you can't use this recognition data by itself. That's why I asked about the intended use of recognition data.